# accessing package lme4

Tags: r

I am trying to use the package doBy, which requires an installation of the package lme4.

I have found the CRAN for it here http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4//index.html

However when I try download the .zip version I get the error "Object not found!".
From what I gather it is not an out of date package (with it last been updated in June of this year).

Does anyone know a way to get around this, or do I just need to wait for lme4 to be fixed/find an alternative for doBy?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps try removing one of the slashes between `lme4` and `index.html` before trying to download the file. So the URL above would be http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html
But ttmaccer's answer below is a preferable way to install packages.

Comment: Why were you trying to install it by downloading the .zip directly?  Did `install.packages("lme4")` not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
install.packages("lme4",repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you use R Studio? I was having the same issue but then I used R Studio's tab "Packages" -> Install tab --> write lme4 from th CRAN repository.