# lme4 package install failing on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: r, install.packages

**EDIT :**

Many thanks to user20650, whose answer solved this problem. But if anyone knows **why** the `.Rprofile` file affects `lme4` install on Ubuntu 12.04, please advise because I'd really like to know.

---

**Original post :**

I'm attempting to install the `doBy` package and am having some issues.  It depends on `lme4`, which for some reason is not compiling from any source I've tried so far.  I've been to a few links on SO including [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967306/accessing-package-lme4) and haven't had any success.

Here are snippets of the errors I'm getting on install.  I tried it three different ways, as noted below.  Anyone know if something's up with `lme4`?

**Attempt 1:**

```
> install.packages('doBy')
# ...
# ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘lme4’
# * removing ‘/home/richard/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/lme4’
# Warning in install.packages :
#   installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
# 
# Successfully loaded .Rprofile at Wed May 21 13:33:34 2014 
# ERROR: dependency ‘lme4’ is not available for package ‘doBy’
# * removing ‘/home/richard/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/doBy’
# Warning in install.packages :
#   installation of package ‘doBy’ had non-zero exit status
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
> install.packages("lme4",repos = "http://r-forge.r-project.org")
# Installing package into ‘/home/richard/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
# (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
# Warning in install.packages :
#   package ‘lme4’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)
```

**Attempt 3:**

```
> install_github(repo = 'lme4/lme4', username = 'stevencarlislewalker')
```

[image]

---

Running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

```
> version
# _                           
# platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
# arch           x86_64                      
# os             linux-gnu                   
# system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
# status                                     
# major          3                           
# minor          1.0                         
# year           2014                        
# month          04                          
# day            10                          
# svn rev        65387                       
# language       R                           
# version.string R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
# nickname       Spring Dance
```

Comment: Maybe `sudo apt-get install r-cran-lme4` can help?  Else you could try to backtrack to older source versions using the CRAN Archive...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, well that got me a bit closer.  Now it's in my list, but I get `Error: package ‘lme4’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it`

Comment: Ok, but you still haven't said which distro you are using.

Comment: (1) I'm not sure why `lme4` wouldn't be available for 3.1 ([package checks](http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_lme4.html) and [CRAN page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) both look fine). (2) I'm not really surprised that `lme4` isn't building on R-forge, but try `repos="http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos"` (3) [sudo apt-get install texinfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652698/texi2dvi-command-not-found)

Comment: Do you have a .Rprofile with .first and .last specified - this caused me issues. If so try temporarily deleting it and try installing lme4 again.

Comment: @user20650, yes.   I actually just added it a few days ago.  I was wondering why my `.First` message was appearing in the error streams.

Comment: I just pushed a possible fix. If you have access to development tools (assume so since you're on Ubuntu), could you try `devtools::github_install("lme4","lme4")` and let me know if it works?

Comment: thanks @DirkEddelbuettel the command `sudo apt-get install r-cran-lme4` make it work for me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (possibly) may  not be an answer to Richard's Q. but does replicate a problem i had installing `lme4` on `ubuntu 12,04` on `Rv3.1`. It would be good if others could reproduce this.

So following on from my comment - noticing that Richard had a .Rprofile, defining `.First` and `.Last` in my `.Rprofile` caused packages not to install.

**Exmaple**

First uninstall `lme4`

```
remove.packages("lme4")
```

Define **.Rprofile** file

```
## .First() run at the start of every R session.
.First <- function() {
cat("\nSuccessfully loaded your .Rprofile at", date(), "\n")
}

## .Last() run at the end of the session
.Last <- function() {
cat("\nGoodbye at ", date(), "\n")
}
```

Open `R`

Try an install `lme4` - no success & similar error to Richard's above

```
install.packages("lme4")

...
* removing ‘/home/admin1/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/lme4’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
```

So rename (or remove) **.Rprofile** file in terminal

```
mv .Rprofile temp.Rprofile
```

Open **R** again and try to install `lme4`

```
install.packages("lme4")

...
* installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (lme4)

 library(lme4)
# Loading required package: Matrix
# Loading required package: Rcpp
```

Comment: Many thanks to you!  This worked perfectly.  I have no clue why the `.Rprofile` affects `lme4` install, but for now I'm not concerned.  Thanks again.

Comment: @RichardScriven; your welcome. Yes, i don't understand either but the `.First` will interfere with the install of multiple packages (so i removed mine). Anyway adding the profile was a case of idle hands being the devils playthings.

Comment: I hope to look into this, but don't know how soon I can get to it.  If you'd like you can add an issue at https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug, should be fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/commit/d670eb204e7c3eab6dcfbd7bb517549a18e09853) in the development version (on Github) and in release 1.1-7 when it comes out (soon?)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments and expanded questions:

- You are shooting yourself in the foot by installing R 3.1.0 onto Ubuntu 12.04.
- You now run an R that is out of sync with packages like `r-cran-lme4` in the distro.
- The good news is that you can ask the distribution for information about the so-called Build-Depends it knows, and rebuild lme4 under R 3.1.0
- Or can benefit from Michael's other work over at launchpad and use his other repo which is what eg the r-travis code does:  `sudo add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/rrutter"` followed by and `sudo add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/c2d4u"`

That last step will give you loads of pre-built packages.  In the long run you are of course better off being to able to build packages from source yourself...

Comment: FWIW I have `lme4` working just fine on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: We all do. The Travis CI infrastructure uses 12.04 as well. And building from source works well for most people, including you and me.

Comment: Then I don't quite understand your first bullet point above: what's wrong with installing 3.1.0 on 12.04?

Comment: Breaks r-cran-lme4 from the distro which was built against the then current 2.* whatever, yielding the error in his comment below his question.

Comment: Honestly, I have been much happier with R on Ubuntu over Windows since I made the switch.  This is really the first install problem I've had.  I may be a linux-lifer now.  It's all so much better and Ubuntu never tells me "I'm not responding" :)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, turns out it was my `.First` call in my `.Rprofile` that was causing the problem.  Got it sorted out now but if you know why that problem occurs, I'd like to know.

Comment: Just wrap it in  `if (interactive()) {}`.  You can have code in `.Rprofile`.

Comment: Yes, but the failure was really the package's fault (output of `Rscript -e` was being fed to an environment variable in `src/Makevars` -- added `--vanilla`)

Comment: I see. We learned that lesson the hard way too as `Rcpp` used to have such `Rscript` calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

solved the problem for me