# lmerTest package install failing on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, lmer

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS precise 32-bit and trying to install the lmerTest package for R version 2.14.1.

When I try to install from the CRAN repository or R-forge: `install.packages("lmerTest")` or `install.packages("lmerTest", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`, I get the error:

> Warning in install.packages : package ‘lmerTest’ is not available (for R version 2.14.1)

So I downloaded the Package Archive File from CRAN and tried to install from this
Package source: lmerTest_2.0-11.tar.gz, but get the error:

> installation of package /home/.../lmerTest_2.0-11.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

I had a similar problem when trying to install lme4, and using the advice from [lme4 package install failing on Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793870/lme4-package-install-failing-on-ubuntu-12-04)
was able to download the package using `sudo apt-get install r-cran-lme4` after which it appeared in my R package list and installed fine from there.

I tried a similar tactic with lmerTest `sudo apt-get install r-cran-lmerTest` but just get

> Unable to locate package r-cran-lmerTest

so really don't know what to do now, bearing in mind that I'm a novice with both Ubuntu and R, any suggestions/help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As of October 28, 2014, it looks like `lmerTest` failed to build. I could not download it either on my machine. Maybe it already failed to build when you submitted your question, two months ago.

Build fails: https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1433

Package info: http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/lmerTest/index.html