# install package on rstudio server ubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: r, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I followed the instructions on randyzwitch's blog (http://randyzwitch.com/r-amazon-ec2/) to install r-studio server on ec2 instance running ubuntu 12.04.

When I start r-studio server and try to install packages, this is what was happening:

```
> install.packages("dplyr")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘dplyr’ is not available (for R version 2.14.1)
Installing package(s) into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Would you like to create a personal library
~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14
to install packages into?  (y/n) y
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘dplyr’ is not available (for R version 2.14.1)
```

I realized I need to update R so I checked out this post and updated it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/218708/installing-latest-version-of-r-base/436491#436491

I am logged in as `sudo` user. When I try to install package now, i get this:

```
> install.packages("plyr")
Installing package into ‘/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘Rcpp’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rcpp_0.11.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2353791 bytes (2.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.2 MB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/plyr_1.8.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 392136 bytes (382 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 382 KB

Warning in install.packages :
  system call failed: Cannot allocate memory
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in install.packages :
  system call failed: Cannot allocate memory
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘plyr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp6Kgx5d/downloaded_packages’
```

I saw this post : [lme4 package install failing on Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793870/lme4-package-install-failing-on-ubuntu-12-04) and followed all instructions but it didn't solve the problem. Still same result. Thoroughly frustrated with trying to run rstudio server on aws. Someone please help!

Comment: ok, i've found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173972/how-do-you-add-swap-to-an-ec2-instance

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the instance type t2.micro?  Try using a more powerful instance with more RAM, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are root user when installing packages:

1. `sudo su` command will take you to root user. Then run your install package code.
2. or use sudo before run you script: `sudo Rscript 1.R`