# Use ggplot and lmerTest in R running with Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, ggplot2, lmertest

for my Statistical analyses, I need to use the Packages ggplot2 and lmerTest.

While installing lmerTest I updated R and was able to use the function. But after this update, I was not able to use ggplot2 anymore. So I downgraded it.
If I want to install lmerTest now it shows the Error:

```
install.packages("lmerTest")

  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lmerTest’ had non-zero exit status

   ---- there is no package called ‘lmerTest’
```

When I Google that problem I just find the answer to update R, but then ggplot2 won't work. I cant use lme4 instead because here is missing the p-value.

**Is there no way to use both, ggplot2 and lmerTest, with Ubuntu??**

I'm definitely no expert. Thanks for any help, sincerely

Maria

Comment: This is surprising. Both `lmerTest` and `ggplot2` should be available with the most recent versions of R. Did you follow the instructions [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) to install R?  Can you show us the results of `sessionInfo()` ?

Comment: Hey Ben, 

 I think I had the same problem as here: [https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9373]. My session info is:

`> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS`

Comment: version 3.6.3 is ancient. I think if you follow the instructions at the link in the comment above you will get the most recent stable version of R (probably 4.2.0) and all your problems might go away ... (most of the problems described in the RStudio issue are either from non-Ubuntu systems or are rather old ...)

Comment: Hey Ben, 
I followed the instructions and running now with R version 4.2.0. ggplot works, but I still can't use lmerTest. Any other idea? 


`------------------ CMAKE NOT FOUND --------------------

CMake was not found on the PATH. Please install CMake:
------------------ CMAKE NOT FOUND --------------------
ERROR: dependency ‘lme4’ is not available for package ‘lmerTest’
* removing ‘/home/maria/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/lmerTest’
Warning in install.packages :
  Installation des Pakets ‘lmerTest’ hatte Exit-Status ungleich 0
there is no packages calles merTest `

Comment: I found [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793870/lme4-package-install-failing-on-ubuntu-12-04] 
I tried to first install `Rcpp` and `Matrix`.  Running this line `mv .Rprofile temp.Rprofile` in R and the ubuntu console and also `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev`. 
Still, it's not working. I'm a beginner and sure it could be my fault.

Comment: If I try to run  `sudo apt-get install r-cran-lme4` it shows up the following error: 
`Depends on: r-cran-rcppeigen (>= 0.3.2.0.2-2) but should not be installed
E: Problems cannot be corrected, you have withheld defective packages.`

Comment: I don't know what the `rcppeigen` problem is, but if you `sudo apt install cmake` you should be able to install the rest of the stuff from source (sorry this is such a pain!)

Comment: This way it works, finally. I hope one day I will solve my problem so quickly too, Hugh Thank you!